# VB.NET ACCESS Database birhtday request X time

Tags: vb.net, where-clause

I have the following problem: I want to extract from my access database the concerts that took place on day X. (Anniversary principle). I wish to release a report from this result. (The state works fine on its own. When I call it from VB without modifying the where clause) I wanted to prepare, for example, 5 states in advance. So I wrote this code:

```
`{'Dim DateJour As String
    Dim I As Integer = 1
    Dim strDB As String = CheminBase & "JH.mdb"
    Dim RptNom As String
    For I = 1 To 5
        DateJour = I
        If DateJour < 10 Then DateJour = "0" & DateJour
        Dim Mois As String = Month(Date.Today)
        If Mois < 10 Then Mois = "0" & Mois
        Dim Annee As String = Year(Date.Today)
        DateJour = DateJour & Mois & Annee
        ClauseWhere = "Format([con_date],ddmm) = Format(" & _ DateAdd(Interval:=DateInterval.Day, I, Date.Today) & ",ddmm) order by con_Date DESC "
        RptNom = "FICHE_JOUR_CONCERT_PLAN"
        OLEOpenReport_PLAN(strDB, RptNom, AcView.acViewPreview, , ClauseWhere)
    Next
    MsgBox("Planification terminée")`}`
```

Here is the code of OLEOpenReport_PLAN

```
`{Private Function OLEOpenReport_PLAN(ByVal strDBName As String, ByVal strRptName As String, Optional ByVal intDisplay As Access.AcView = Access.AcView.acViewNormal, Optional ByVal strFilter As String = "", Optional ByVal strWhere As String = "") As Boolean

    Dim bReturn As Boolean = True
    Try
    Dim objAccess As New Access.Application
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDBName, False)
    objAccess.DoCmd.OpenReport(strRptName, intDisplay, strFilter, strWhere, _ Access.AcWindowMode.acWindowNormal)
    objAccess.DoCmd.OutputTo(Access.AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport, strRptName, _ OutputFormat:="PDF", "C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\AppData\Roaming\IP-Informatique _ Pourrieres\J H L Appli\Editions\Editions Planifiees\" & strRptName & "_" & DateJour & _".pdf",,,,)
    objAccess.Quit(Access.AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveNone)
    objAccess = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
    bReturn = False      
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Erreur Automation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
    MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Try
    Return bReturn
End Function}`
```

At runtime I receive an "Operator absent" error at the level of the clausewhere. I also tried:

```
'{'ClauseWhere = "Format([con_date],ddmm) = Format(Date()+" & 1 & ",ddmm) order by con_Date DESC "'}'
```

which gives me the same error.

To be complete, here is the code of the state request:

```
'SELECT CONCERTS.CON_Date, CITIES.VIL_NOM
FROM CITIES INNER JOIN CONCERTS ON CITIES.IDVILLE = CONCERTS.IDVILLE;
```

`
Thank you in advance for your help.

Thierry

Comment: While probably not the answer you're after, Store dates as dates, this avoids any issues around formatting and conversions.  If you need to display dates to the end users in some specific format do it on display.  Also consider using parameters rather than string concatenations to build your sql, will make your code more robust and maintainable

Comment: No one has any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dates are stored as Dates...

I only know the vb end of this. Using the the Day and Month functions of Access Sql compare these to the Day and Month of your desired ann. date to get the concerts on this date in any year.

```
Private Function GetAnniversaries(AnnDate As Date) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim selectString = "SELECT CONCERTS.CON_Date, CITIES.VIL_NOM
                        FROM CITIES 
                        INNER JOIN CONCERTS ON CITIES.IDVILLE = CONCERTS.IDVILLE 
                        Where Day(CONCERTS.CON_Date) = @Day And Month(CONCERTS.CON_Date) = @Month;"
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(selectString, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Day", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Day(AnnDate)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Month(AnnDate)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
    'To see what was returned
    Dim AnniversaryDate = Now
    Dim dt = GetAnniversaries(AnniversaryDate)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Thank you, I will take a look. I had found a poor solution but it worked. (Temporary Table)...